# Python: counting number of co-orindates within specified windows

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tab delimited files. Each has two columns, one for chromosome and one for column. I want to identify the number of positions in file2 that are within a specified window range of the positions in file1, and then check in the next window, and the next and so forth.

So if this is the first row from file 1:

```
1 10500
```

And this is from file 2:

```
1 10177
1 10352
1 10616
1 11008
1 11012
1 13110
1 13116
1 13118
1 13273
1 13550
```

If the window is of size 1000, the following co-ordinates from file 2 fall within this window:

```
1 10177
1 10352
1 10616
```

The second window should then be 2000 in size and therefore these co-ordinates fall within this window:

```
1 10177
1 10352
1 10616
1 11008
1 11012
```

My files are split by chromosomes so this needs to be taken into account also.

I have started by creating the following function:

```
#Function counts number of variants in a window of specified size around a specified
#genomic position
def vCount(nsPos, df, windowSize):
    #If the window minimum is below 0, set to 0
    if(nsPos - (windowSize/2) < 0): 
        low = 0
    else:
        low = nsPos - (windowSize/2)

    high = high = nsPos + (windowSize/2)
    #calculate the length (i.e. the number) of variants in the subsetted data.
    diversity = len(df[(df['POS'] >= low) & (df['POS'] <= high)])

    return(diversity)
```

This calculates the number for a single co-ordinate from file 1. However, what I want to do is calculate the number for every co-ordinate and then calculate the average. For this I use the following function, which uses the above function:

```
#Function to apply vCount function across the entire positional column of df
def windowAvg(NSdf, variantsDF, window):
    x=NSdf.POS.apply(vCount, df=variantsDF, windowSize=window)
    return(x)
```

This also works fine, but as I mentioned above, this needs to be done over multiple genomic windows, and then the means must be plotted. So I have created a function that uses a loop and then plots the result:

```
def loopNplot(NSdf, variantsDF, window):
    #store window
    windows = list(range(1,101))
    #store diversity
    diversity = []

    #Loop through windows appending to the list.
    for i in range(window, 101000, window):

        #Create a list to hold counts for each chromosome (which we then take the mean of)
        tempList = []

        #Loop through chromosomes
        for j in NSdf['CHROM']:
            #Subset NS polymorphisms
            subDF = vtable.loc[(vtable['CHROM'] == j)].copy()
            #Subset all variants
            subVar = all_variants.loc[(all_variants['CHROM'] == j)].copy()

            x = windowAvg(subDF, subVar, i)
            #convert series to list
            x = x.tolist()
            #extend templist to include x
            tempList.extend(x)

        #Append mean of tempList - counts of diversity - to list.
        diversity.append(sum(tempList)/len(tempList))


    #Copy diversity
    divCopy = list(diversity)
    #Add a new first index of 0
    diversity = [0] + diversity
    #Remove last index
    diversity = diversity[:-1]
    #x - diversity to give number of variants in each window
    div = list(map(operator.sub, divCopy, diversity))

    plt.scatter(windows, div)

    plt.show()
```

The issue here is that file1 has 11609 rows, and file2 has 13758644 rows. Running the above function is extremely sluggish and I would like to know if there is any way to optimise or change the script to make things more efficient?

I am more than happy to use other command line tools if Python is not the best way to go about this.